# how to determine the origin of trash

Tags: 15.04

I have moved a config folder and a local folder in the trash! I want to figure out the origin of these folder before I restore them. I think I may have touched the delete key on my computer by mistake. In windows, before you moving anyfile into the trash, a confirmation will pop out. However, this functionality is not embedded in Ubuntu.

So here I have 2 questions: 
1. How to trace the origin of file/folders in the Trash? 
2. How to set up a confirmation before moving anything to Trash?

Answer (score 1):

If you use list view,you can see the original location.
[image: Trash]